# Why pristine props does not disable button for both Redux-Fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, submit, redux-form

I have 2 Fields and a submit button. The 2 Fields are controlled by redux-form. Both Fields need to be filled before pressing the submit button, so I use the pristine and submitting props to disable the button if the 2 Fields are empty.
The problem is that if I fill one of the 2 Fields, the button becomes enabled but what I want it the button to be enabled after filling both Fields.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
 <div id="product-searchbar">
  <Field
   component="TextField"
   type="text"
   name="productId"
   placeholder="Enter a name product..."
  />
 </div>
 <Field
  component="Dropdown"
  header="Choose a product"
  name="type"
  items={[
   { value: "product a", id: 1 },
   { value: "product b", id: 2 }
  ]}
 />
 <button
  type="submit"
  disabled={pristine || submitting}
 >
  <SaveIcon />
 </button>
</form>

let ComponentContainer= reduxForm({
 form: "formProduct"
})(ComponentWrapped);
```

Comment: Are your form's values initialized from states values? (https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/) because `pristine` is only used in this situation. If it's not the case, you should just set these fields as `required`

Comment: @SamHecquet yes, they are initialized from states value. I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pristine` means "none of the fields" value properties differ from their initial properties", so as soon as one field has a value different than the values you initialized, `pristine` will be set to `false`. You use this variable to enable the `reset()` function.

What you want to do is to make these 2 fields mandatory. There's two way to do it: 
Either you just set these two fields as required, like this:

```
<Field
   component="TextField"
   type="text"
   name="authId"
   placeholder="Enter an auth-Id..."
   required
/>
```

Or you follow this [Field-Level Validation Example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) and add a `required` validation:

```
const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required');

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)}>
      <div id="authId-searchbar">
        <Field
          component="TextField"
          type="text"
          name="authId"
          placeholder="Enter an auth-Id..."
          validate={required}
        />
      </div>
      <Field
        component="Dropdown"
        header="Choose a credential type"
        name="type"
        items={[
          { value: "product a", id: 1 },
          { value: "product b", id: 2 }
        ]}
        validate={required}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        disabled={pristine || submitting}
      >
        <SaveIcon />
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.